# Multisite Backup Plugin

Tags: plugins, multisite, backup

Hi

Is it possible to backup each blog separately from a multisite installation?

Can I do it with: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backwpup/ ?

Comment: Plugin recommendations have been made off topic, as aside current version of BackupBuddy should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this as a feature to add to [DBC Backup 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dbc-backup-2/) (my plugin).  Currently the plugin will backup the WordPress database for your entire multisite.

The problem I found with wanting to backup a subsite is that it is impossible for the subsite 'owner' to restore from that backup.

The plugin could save all the tables in the WordPress SQL like `wp_7_options` and `wp_7_posts`  but

- the sub-site user can not restore the database (they'd need access to PHPMyAdmin for example) and
- they can't use the backup to make their own WordPress single unless they can edit the SQL.

So all in all ... I think this is a nice to have but not sure if it's worth trying to develop it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult one...

I've worked with [XCloner](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/), [Backup to Dropbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-backup-to-dropbox/) and [Backup Buddy](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/), but never seen this feature.

After learning Multisite, I've mainly used BB, a premium one and pretty good. It cannot handle this, only exporting a subsite into a single site.

When I used it, Backup to Dropbox didn't had any Multisite capabilities. And, if activated in subsites, exposed all the *blogs.dir* folder.

I'm not certain about XCloner, as I stopped using it long ago. But it is certainly a good plugin.